# Putting time.Time value into postgres from a Go structure

Tags: postgresql, go

I've had to create a customeTime structure to enable me to marshal/unmarshal some time strings into another structure for an API I'm having to develop against that passes around time values as strings (which makes life fun for all of us).

It seems the marshal/unmarshal is working OK, but in other part of the code I have to put the date into a postgresql database and I'm getting

```
sql: converting argument $7 type: unsupported type utils.CustomTime, a struct
```

The utils.CustomeTime is just a simple struct

```
type CustomTime struct {
    time.Time
}
```

I guess what I'm asking is how do I get to the time.Time within the structure for the sql statement?

The overall structure is

```
type Entry struct {
    .....
    TradingDate      utils.CustomTime `json:"tradingDate"`
    .....
}
```

In the SQL I've got e.TradingDate as the variable (e being the incoming event structure).

Does this make sense?

EDIT!!
This has to be the most crazy coincidence to date. The database server had died (mostly) but still alive enough to accept connections.  After much grunt work, its now back and EVERYTHING is working!!  Have removed extraneous guff above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your custom type has to implement the [`driver.Valuer`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer) interface:

> Types implementing Valuer interface are able to convert themselves to a driver Value.

```
type CustomTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (c CustomTime) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return driver.Value(c.Time), nil
}
```

Then, assuming you'll also want to scan the postgres column back into your custom type, you'll have to implement [`sql.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner):

```
func (c *CustomTime) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    switch t := src.(type) {
    case time.Time:
        c.Time = t
        return nil
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("column type not supported")
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the fact that the `Scan(src interface{}) error` has a pointer receiver, because you want to actually modify the value the receiver points to.